# Why is the Cross-ratio $ \lambda (z_1 , \dots , z_4 ) $ the image of $ z_4 $ under $ T $ satisfying some conditions?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

Could someone please explain to me why is the cross-ratio :
$$ \lambda ( z_1 , \dots , z_4 ) = \dfrac{(z_1 - z_2)(z_3 - z_4)}{(z_1 - z_3)(z_2 - z_4)} $$
the image of $ z_4 $ under the ( unique ) linear map $ T \ : \ \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1 $ such that : $ \begin{cases} T(z_1) = 1 \\ T(z_2) = \infty \\ T(z_3) = 0 \end{cases} $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{CP}^1$. Consider the map $T : \mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ given by

$$T(z) = \frac{(z_1 - z_2)(z_3 - z)}{(z_1 - z_3)(z_2 - z)}.$$

Then $T(z_1) = 1$, $T(z_2) = \infty$, and $T(z_3) = 0$. Now note that

$$T(z_4) = \frac{(z_1 - z_2)(z_3 - z_4)}{(z_1 - z_3)(z_2 - z_4)} = \lambda(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4).$$

Comment: Thank you.  :) Why is $T$ unique satisfying $ \begin{cases} T(z_1) =1 \\ T(z_2 ) = \infty \\ T( z_3 ) = 0 \end{cases} $ ?

Comment: Every Möbius transformation is of the form $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$ and $ad - bc \neq 0$. If you substitute in $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ and set them equal to their desired values, you get three equations. This allows you to determine three of the four values $a, b, c, d$. It turns out the remaining one disappears.